# Vue3 + Cordova + Admob

Tags: vue.js, cordova, admob, vuejs3, cordova-admob

how can I include admob in a vue3 and cordova project. I've tried so many ways from different sites but none of them worked so far or I don't know where to put the admob code..

Basically I create a Vue3 project, then

```
vue add cordova
```

Inside **src-cordova**:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-admob
```

and the vue build (dist) folder I've moved it to **src-cordova** www folder.

But where exactly do I add the code bellow ??

```
on onDeviceReady() {
      document.removeEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
      
      // Set AdMobAds options:
      admob.setOptions({
        publisherId:           "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/BBBBBBBBBB",  // Required
        interstitialAdId:      "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/IIIIIIIIII",  // Optional
        autoShowBanner:        true,                                      // Optional
        autoShowRInterstitial: false,                                     // Optional
        autoShowRewarded:      false,                                     // Optional
        tappxIdiOS:            "/XXXXXXXXX/Pub-XXXX-iOS-IIII",            // Optional
        tappxIdAndroid:        "/XXXXXXXXX/Pub-XXXX-Android-AAAA",        // Optional
        tappxShare:            0.5                                        // Optional
      });
      
      // Start showing banners (atomatic when autoShowBanner is set to true)
      admob.createBannerView();
      
      // Request interstitial ad (will present automatically when autoShowInterstitial is set to true)
      admob.requestInterstitialAd();

      // Request rewarded ad (will present automatically when autoShowRewarded is set to true)
      admob.requestRewardedAd();
    }
    
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```